# Every other character is NULL after reading a binary file in Visual C++, not other compilers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am reading a file using fopen/fread.  On Visual Studio, every second character is NULL.  Using other compilers, or by creating a new Visual Studio project, this parses correctly.

I can confirm that the file is not UTF-16, with every other byte being NULL.  I viewed it in a hex editor.

I tried an alternate implementation that used iostreams and it does the same thing.

I am compiling without _MBCS and have set Character Set to "Not Set" in the property pages.

```
Uint8 *BinaryFileToMem( const char *filename, Sint64 *len )
{
    FILE *hnd = fopen( filename, "rb" );
    if ( !hnd )
    {
        Warning("Could not read %s", filename );
        return NULL;
    }

    long int beginning = ftell( hnd );
    fseek( hnd, 0, SEEK_END );
    long int end = ftell( hnd );

    long int filesize = end - beginning;
    if ( len )
    {
        *len = (Sint64)filesize;
    }

    fclose( hnd );

    // reopen for read
    Uint8 *body = new Uint8[ (unsigned int)filesize ];
    hnd = fopen( filename, "rb" );
    Assert( hnd );
    size_t bytesread = fread( body, sizeof(Uint8), filesize, hnd );
    Assert( bytesread == filesize );

    fclose( hnd );

    return body;
}
```

If the file contains "hello", the resulting code would be:

```
body[0] == 'h'
body[1] == \0
body[2] == 'e'
body[4] == \0
```

... and so forth

This is Visual Studio 2012, using the VS2012 platform toolset (v110).  I am linking against Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD).

Comment: Sounds like an UTF-16 issue to me.

Comment: Could be a multibyte character issue (may not be UTF).

Comment: Why close/reopen? Just [`rewind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rewind) it. And when you open a file, its starting position will always be zero. Any why use C files instead of C++ streams?

Comment: "or by creating a new Visual Studio project" - can you compare the new project to the old project file and see if anything's different?

Comment: Yes, it looks like UTF-16.  But why would fopen with "rb" insert NULL characters when calling fread()?  That seems like a mistake regardless of any unicode setting -- fopen is encoding agnostic.

Comment: Comparing Visual Studio project settings is notoriously difficult.

Comment: @mlabbe tried using diff on the files as text?

Comment: @mlabbe So's psychic debugging, and you're not giving us much else to go on. If making a new project fixes it then it has to be a project file issue doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `fread` is not affected by Visual Studio settings, except warnings about how unsafe it is.

Most likely explanation for Visual C++ result is that the file that's read by this code contains UTF-16 encoded text, or the UCS-2 subset. If UCS-2 subset, then you can represent each character as a `wchar_t`. For full UTF-16 some characters (in the sense of Unicode code points) will need 2 `wchar_t`; these are called "surrogate pairs".

The "Using other compilers, or by creating a new Visual Studio project, this parses correctly." seems to indicate that some different file is read.

Comment: It's not a different file.  And as I stated, I am looking at the file in a hex editor.  The first few bytes are:  3c3f 786d 6c20 7665 7273 696f 6e3d.  How can that possibly generate NULLs after every byte when using fread to load it in.

Comment: @mlabbe: Windows' WordPad reports that those bytes mean "<?xml version=". Which is different from the "hello" in your example data. So either the files are different, or your example is wholly *hypothetical*.

Comment: The example was hypothetical.  I just tested it with a file that contains "hello" and it failed, so it is no longer wholly hypothetical.